# ion_aouth sets empty field TO when registering a new user

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, ion-auth

I have a localhost setup with CodeIgniter and ion_auth

I'm trying to let users register their own accounts. The users are created correctly in the database, but the email is not being sent because the **TO** field is **empty**. I've tried to search in the code for a clue on what/where change things, but I haven't found anything yet.

Here is a picture of what I get as output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2szL.png

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating a test controller/method to send emails and make sure that works correctly stand alone from Ion Auth.

Comment: I made a test controller and it works properly, but when a user registers, the email is not being sent. I'm using `register(...)` with the required data, the activation code is saved into the DB. I wonder if I have to do it separately or it should be automatic?